# О примерах синонимов и антонимов

Tags: синонимы, антонимы

Являются ли *слова конь, кляча, скакун, лошадки* синонимами? Являются ли слова *скакун* и *кляча* антонимами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перечисленные слова, в основном, являются эмоционально-оценочными и стилистическими синонимами. "Конь" - высокое, "лошадь" - нейтральное, "кляча" - разговорное, имеющее отрицательно-оценочную окраску. "Лошадки", за счет суффикса субъективной  оценки также имеет разговорную окраску + ласкательный оттенок. Слово "скакун", стилистически нейтральное, имеет дополнительный смысловой оттенок в своем основном "предметно-логическом значении" :«лошадь, отличающаяся высокими беговыми качествами". Слова "скакун" и "кляча" в языке не являются антонимами, хотя в  конкретном словоупотреблении, за счет смысловых и оценочных установок говорящего (пишущего) могут становиться контекстуальными антонимами.

Comment: Впрочем, слово "кляча" обладает своим дополнительным значением: это не просто "лошадь", но "тощая, слабая, больная лошадь" (Словарь под ред. проф. Д.Н. Ушакова). Так что по отношению к другим словам этого ряда оно выступает и кака стилистический. и как семантический синоним. Тогда как слово "скакун" по отношению к слову "лошадь" является  только семантическим синонимом.